# Chain pipes at jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pipe, jquery-callback, chain

I'm using jQuery v1.7, so I'm not able to use `then`. I need to make several nested ajax calls and I want to rid off nested callback calls. I found that at version 1.7 i can use `pipe` method. But after googling I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. I have code which looks like this:

```
step1().pipe(step2, fail).pipe(step3, fail).done(step4, fail)
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass async call results from `step1` to `step2` and so on or call fail function in case of error. Finally I call done method.

Signature of `step2` is:

```
function step2(data) {
    ...
}
```

I omit 2 extra params as they are not necessary for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests I can see that it works:

```
step1().pipe(step2, fail).pipe(step3, fail).done(step4, fail)
```

for jQuery v1.7